# If the element is not available on a web page how to retry upto 3 times before failing in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am implementing a wrapper method for a retry mechanism for finding WebElements on a web page, my requirement is **If the element is not available , retry upto 3 times before failing** how do i implement this method, below is my code is it correct ?

```
public static WebElement findElementWithRetry(WebDriver driver, By by, int retryCount){
            WebElement element = null;
            try {
                wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //TODO: handle exception
                for(int i=0; i<retryCount; i++){
                    element = driver.findElement(by);
                    if(element.isDisplayed())
                        return element;
                }
            }
            return element;
        }
```

Comment: Instead of retrying 3 times, why not just wait 3 times as long ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= retryCount; i++) {
    try { 
        WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
        if (element.isDisplayed()) {
            return element
        }
    }
    catch(TimeOutException e) {
        // ignore
    }
}
throw new ValueError(String.format("Element %s not found after %s retries", by, retryCount));
```